# Should I use CSS or Javascript to display information dependent on screen size? does it matter which?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have was wondering which would be more correct when choosing what information to display be it `<video>` or `<img>` tags to show depending on screen size of the device. Was wondering if it would be better to use CSS or JavaScript or some other method to do it

would it be better practice to use JavaScript something like

```
var screenSize = screen.width;

if (screenSize >= 500) {
    //display image or video or text
} else if (screenSize >= 1000) {
   //dislpay a different image or video or text
} else {
   //display something different
}
```

or to rather use CSS media queries something like

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 0) {
   .mobile-version{
      display:block
   }
   .tablet-version{
      display:none;
   }
   .desktop-version{
      display:none;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500) {
    .mobile-version{
      display:none;
   }
   .tablet-version{
      display:block;
   }
   .desktop-version{
      display:none;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000) {
    .mobile-version{
      display:none;
   }
   .tablet-version{
      display:none;
   }
   .desktop-version{
      display:block;
   }
}
```

any advice would be appreciated (thanks in advance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a matter of preference and depends on your application.

If you intent to have more complex or dynamic elements which contain some kind of logic, then JavaScript might be better suited and give you more control. Maybe you would like to have user preferences like video-auto-play on/off, and so on.

However, if you just want to perform simple conditional display, then CSS is your friend.

My advice would be to choose the simplest solution for you, which seems to be CSS, and avoid mixing both in a single application.

Comment: At the moment for my application It is a video that is auto-playing in the background depending on the screen size of the device i would like different versions so that it will show everything in better quality

Comment: okay awesome so then ill give each source in the video a different class and hide depending on what is needed thanks man

Answer (score 2):

For what you're looking to accomplish I'd have to say media queries just due to how simple they are to set up/adjust. Why re-invent the wheel right?

Answer (score 0):

> would it be better practice to use JavaScript something like ...

**Go ahead with CSS** instead as it is intended to solve this problem of yours.

BUT, you also mentioned using `<video>` tags. While for resizing the HTML tags using CSS is sufficient, you **might need to use javascript** to pass desired resolution to the video player, depending on viewport size. Especially, if you have multiple resolutions of the same videofile. (you don't want to play 1080p in a 640x320 box) In that case, you could get screen width using `window.outerWidth`, `window.innerWidth`, `document.documentElement.clientWidth`. All these **produce different results**, but the second will give you values identical to CSS breakpoints.

Comment: okay so i have 2 different videos that will play depending on size, (one portrait for mobile versions) and then a more landscape one (same video just sized differently) for tablets and desktop any advice on how i would do it?

Comment: This depends a lot on the player you intend to use. In case the player can detect its' own dimensions on screen, it will also choose an according video source from the ones you let it use.

In case the player is not 'smart', you need to dynamically load the video source after you detect these player dimensions: IF video element or the DIV wrapping it has width of X, then use widthX.mp4 as source.

Comment: Also, in your scenario, if the video isn't full screen, the size of the actual player is more important then window size. Then, after `.onload()`, use JS to detect the video element dimension and load a video source based on them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your application or project. 
If you want to show dynamic element or logic then javascript is a good option and for the simple conditional display, then CSS will be the best option.

I think media query is enough for displaying conditional element.